# Online tutorials specific for building graph databases using Cassandra and Titan and Solr for search

Tags: database, graph, solr, cassandra, titan

Does anybody know any good tutorials for learning how to use Cassandra along with Titan for storing graph databases and Solr as a search mechanism?

I am new in this area, so I actually don't know why people use both Cassandra and Titan together in their projects?

If anyone know any good documentation for implementing a sample project in the mentioned setting, I will be appreciated to let me know about that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This titan documentation is good to start with: http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index.html

and also this quick guide about cassandra: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/cassandra_quick_guide.htm

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/02/getting-started-titan-using-cassandra-solr/) is a short tutorial I wrote on how to setup titandb with cassandra and solr.

To answer your other question:
You can configure titan to use different backends as a storage (cassandra, BerkeleyDB, HBase). To include search functionality like fulltext search or geospatial search, you'd have to configure titan to use a search backend (elastic, solr or directly lucene).